# Include CSS and JS to Custom Library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a custom library in Codeigniter and initialized and running well. I am in need of help to include the CSS and JS which are needed for my custom library. I am creating my custom library as a plugin.

Folder Structure:

1. Application

   1.1. libraries

   1.1.1 custom_library_folder

   - CSS
   - JS
   - Custom_Library_File.php
   - sk_form.php

**Custom_Library_File.php**

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sdkat{

    function __construct()
    {}

    public function sdkat_library()
    {
        include('sk_form.php');
    }
}
?>
```

In the sk_form.php I am in need to include the CSS and JS Files for my designing purpose.

**sk_form.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/libraries/sdkat/css/style.css">
<form method="post">

    <div class="input">
        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

The CSS is not calling and I get Access forbidden! error when I view the CSS in the Browser.

Note: I am in need to include the CSS and JS from my custom library. Could anyone help me to figure it out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to include files on Application path

```
 <?php 
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Sdkat{

        function __construct()
        {

        $this->load->helper('url');

        }

        public function sdkat_library()
        {
             require_once(APPPATH."custom_library_folder/sk_form.php");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I am getting the Error: Undefined property: Sdkat::$load

Comment: you can also set url in your autoload file.. $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: @vikas. actually my css has to be loaded in the custom library file not in the entire project

Comment: so you have eroor like undefined property sdkat:load?? can you extend class ci_controller?

Comment: can u get answer?

Comment: class Sdkat extends CI_Controller {   extends class name CI_Controller

Answer (score 0):

It's because of security reasons, CI added .htaccess file inside application folder in your file system. Inside that they written like ..

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Because of `Require all denied` its restricting files.

To overcome this create a .htaccess inside your "sdkat" folder and add the following line.

```
Require all granted
```

- Restart server if needed
- Add Codeigniter's default index.html inside "sdkat" folder and all it's sub folders to avoid directory browsing.

Comment: Will check and let you be informed @Mohammed. Sorry for delay